# Change style of a frame using CSS

Tags: css, stylish

I'm learning a bit of CSS from test and trial, and couldn't find a solution for this particular problem through web searches.

I help a person who's learning English, and she uses a lot of Google Translate on a small screen. I've been able to hide Google's toolbars and the annoying "Download Google Chrome" popup with the following (I'm using Stylish):

```
.jfk-butterBar.jfk-butterBar-info.jfk-butterBar-shown {
  display:none!important;
}

#gb {
  display:none!important;
}

#gt-appbar {
  display:none!important;
}
```

The problem is: they are hidden, but the translated website is left on a frame with a space that varies from 70px to 160px on the top. The corresponding piece of code I'm talking about is here:

```
<div id="contentframe" style="top: 70px; left: 0px;">
```

And this is the best I could come up with after searching, but doesn't work:

```
#contentframe {
  top: 0px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `#contentframe { top: 0 !important; }` on the last piece of css? inline styles have a higher specifity than ID declarations.

Comment: Yeah, that works! Turn it into an answer and I'll choose it as the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to outweigh the specifity of the inline-style `top: 70px;` with the `!important` rule.

```
#contentframe {
    top: 0 !important;
}
```